# Meaning of 'deprive them of any sense'

Tags: meaning

> Thus they are compelled to cut all connection between their statements and experience; and precisely by this procedure they **deprive them of any sense**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *deprive them of any sense* the word "them" refers to "their statements" in the preceding phrase.  "Deprive" means "to take away from" or "to withhold from".  "Sense" in this context means "meaning".  So the sentence with *deprive them of any sense* is saying that their statements do not make sense because they are separated from experience.

Answer (score 0):

Because their statement have no connection to their experience, their statements are not sensible.